# Prove for all convergent sequence $\phi\rightarrow x_0$, the set $\{x_0\}\cup \phi(\mathbb{N})$ is compact

Tags: general-topology

Prove for all convergent sequence $\phi\rightarrow x_0$, the set $A=\{x_0\}\cup  \phi(\mathbb{N})$ is compact

**My work**

Let $U=\{\bigcup_\alpha U_\alpha:\alpha\in\sum\}$ a open covers of $A$, then for some $U_\alpha$, we have $x_0\in U_\alpha$. Then for $\epsilon>0$ we have $B(x_0,\epsilon)\subset U_0$.

Here i'm little stuck, because my space $(X,\tau)$ not necessarily is a metric space. I'm a little confused here. Can someone help me?

Comment: In fact $B(x_0,\epsilon)$ contains all but finitely many $\phi(n).$

Comment: If you consider balls, then it's no longer general topology, but metric spaces instead.

Comment: is general topology, because is a general space @Adayah

Comment: Balls don't make sense in general topological spaces. So if your space doesn't have a metric, it was incorrect of you to even write $B(x_0, \epsilon)$.

Comment: Definitions are tools to be used. State the def'n of  convergence and use it. Always  use the definitions.

Answer (score 2):

Recall the definition of convergence in a general topological space: $L$ is a limit of a sequence if for every neighborhood of $L$ the sequence is eventually in that neighborhood. It doesn't depend on balls or distances.

So once you have chosen an $U_\alpha$ that contains $x_0$, it will also contain all but finitely many elements of the sequence. Finitely many additional $U_\alpha$s will cover the rest.